# Jwt Claim Names

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

What is the standards based way to name claims in ASPNetCore?

For example, I am using the following to create a JWT, but I would like to take the strings out of it.

```
var claims = new[]
                                {
                    new Claim("UserName", user.UserName),
                    new Claim("UserId", user.Id),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new Claim("AppUserId", appUser.Id.ToString()),
                    new Claim("TenantId", user.TenantId.ToString())
                    };
```

There seems to be two different dotnetcore classes for this:

```
 `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtRegisteredClaimNames`
 `System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes`
```

Which ones should I be using?

The JwtRegisteredClaimNames look like this: `public const string Sub = "sub";`
Whereas ClaimTypes look like this: public const string Name = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name";

I don't get when to the different. Why a url in the second case?

Answer (score 12):

Generally, the identity representations inside Dotnet framework and Dotnetcore both use `System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes` enumeration. The claim type string is coming from WS-* era and Windows Identity Foundation. I think it is not changed due to backward compatibility.

`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtRegisteredClaimNames` represent claim types from newer protocols.

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4
- http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken

So if you are using newer protocols(OAuth, OpenId Connect) you can use `JwtRegisteredClaimNames` as well. Sometimes you may need to map between two claim types.

Also, `sub` is usually a unique identifier, for none unique property like the name you can use `FamilyName` or `GivenName`.

You may also define your own claim types as well.

Comment: It's not really a choice. Microsoft issued tokens follow the names listed in the System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes namespace; I dont think this depends on the client side framework u are using as evidenced by a simple postman request.